# How to use Spectrogram to treat audio data using the same tool as computer vision

Tags: audio, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, spectrogram

I encountered this question in a Deep learning book where it introduces CNN. The whole problem is illustrated here:

Audio data is often represented as a one-dimensional sequence.

1. When might you want to impose locality and translation invariance for audio?
2. Derive the convolution operations for audio.
3. Can you treat audio using the same tools as computer vision? Hint: use the spectrogram.

I am a new player in deep learning. I tried to search on Google and Stackoverflow but didn't find how to utilize Spectrogram. Thank you